# Timeout on multiple POSTs to web api hosted in mono xsp

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mono, xsp

I've been using XSP to host my ASP.Net MVC website for a while (.Net 4.5.1, combination of Razor and WebForms) quite successfully.

However, when I come to use the WebApi, I am experiencing a problem (only on XSP, not IIS) :- the request stream resulting from POSTing to the reused connection times out when reading.

If I set "Connection" : "close" in the headers, then it works fine, or if I set HTTP to be anything other that 1.1, it also works (however, I am making the requests from a browser, so do not have control over these header values)

To test this, I overrode the standard JSON formatting:

```
    public class JsonFormmatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public JsonFormmatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return Deserialize(readStream, type);
    }

    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
    {
        Serialize(value, writeStream);
    }

    public static void Serialize(object value, Stream s)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s))
        using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
            jsonWriter.Flush();
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(Stream s, Type type)
    {
        // READING JSON FROM THIS STREAM TIMES OUT!
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s, Encoding.Default, true, 100000, true))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
            return ser.Deserialize(jsonReader, type);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
```

And then, in App_Stat/WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    while (config.Formatters.Count > 0)
    {
        config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    config.Formatters.Add(new JsonFormmatter());
```

Posting JSON to an action on my web api controller times out when deserializing from the request stream.

Anyone have any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: Hello. I am using newest version of mono, with windows 10. It seems to affect all versions of XSP. It is fine in Firefox as FF seems to send a http 1.0 request (which, looking at xsp source, doesn't result in connection reuse)

Comment: Hi - sorry - I downloaded 4.6.1.5 and used that.

Comment: has this ever worked with a previous version of mono? are you aware that XSP is not recommended for production use?

Comment: I was previously using v3.0.0.0 and that didn't work this scenario, which is why I tried newest stable release, which has exactly the same problem

Comment: the web stack of Mono has always been lagging behind .NET because there were not much economical efforts put into it (also, using Mono in Windows doesn't help, as Mono has better compatibility layers with Mac&Linux --there is not much point in running Mono for Windows given that Windows comes with .NET--), so you're likely hitting a bug that no one has ever fixed; you have three options: a) wait for someone to fix the bug; b) fix the bug yourself (or pay someone to fix it); c) move to dot net core

Comment: Or option d) someone has experienced the same problem and has a work-around/suggestion, which is why I posted this question.